# Clear socket buffer of CAN adapter

Tags: command-line, socket, buffer, canbus

I have a USB/CAN adapter, from `lsusb`:

> OpenMoko, Inc. Geschwister Schneider CAN adapter

it provides a socket interface, from `ip addr`:

```
5: can0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 10 link/can
```

On the bus there are other devices that sends data continuously.
If I reboot my PC, I cannot send/receive data anymore, because I get the following error:

> No buffer space available

I guess that while the device is "disconnected" from the PC (because it's rebooting, but still powered) the internal buffers fill up.

Is there a command I can issue to clear the buffers?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the python-can library offers a solution to this

https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/python-can/develop/python-can.pdf

> The python-can library provides Controller Area Network support for
> Python, providing common abstractions to different hardware devices,
> and a suite of utilities for sending and receiving messages on a CAN
> bus.

One of the functions offered there is `flush_tx_buffer()`

> flush_tx_buffer()
>
> Discard every message that may be queued in the output buffer(s).

The library can be downloaded from various locations, including from the github repo at https://github.com/hardbyte/python-can